# Need to catch event before Outlook.MailItem.Send

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Currently I am developing an outlook addin with Visual Studio 2015 and VSTO.
I want to set the salutations according to the mail-recepients.

So on MailItem.PropertyChange I read out the recepients and set the salutation. 
After this the user can change the salutation afterwards.

Stupidly Outlook throws a new MailItem.PropertyChange-Event when I click on "Send" and my changed salutation is overwritten with the default salutation.

I already tried to catch the MailItem.Send-Event, but this PropertyChange is thrown before the Send-Event.

So I need to know if there is a solution to catch the buttonpress directly or something else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't capture the click event on the Send button because it is not exposed (unless you change the form design and add your own button).  I would just set some boolean flags that you've set the salutations and don't change them again if those flags are true.

Comment: I already set some booleans, but then I loose the possibility that the To-Property can be changed.

Comment: Finally I managed my main-problem: You should never call "Save"-Method during PropertyChange-Event. This should be handled in a seperate thread or a timer. Your answer is right. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you cannot use the Outlook Object Model in background threads - it will likely cause Outlook to crash.  Also, use Windows.Forms.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer, as the latter uses secondary threads.

Comment: Yes, I used Windows.Forms.Timer to solve this problem. You are right. Threads won't work.